# Slick Plain SQL implicit GetResult for table with has-many JOIN

Tags: mysql, scala, slick

I'm using Slick Plain SQL and I've got a table schema something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(191) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE images (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  url VARCHAR(191) NOT NULL,
  user_id INT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id)
  ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

and a case class that looks like this:

```
case class User(name: String, imageUrls: Array[String])
```

Is it possible to write my query and implicit `GetResult` so that I can do something like this:

```
val u = Q.query[String, User]("""
  SELECT
    users.name, images.url
  FROM
    users
    INNER JOIN images ON images.user_id = users.id
  WHERE
    users.name = ?
""").first(name)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The one-to-many relationship is the tricky thing here.  Not sure there is anything out of the box to allow a `GetResult` to be able to collapse the records down so that the image urls get aggregated on a single `User` record by user id.  But you could just do this processing yourself with a couple of tweaks to your example:

```
case class User(name: String, imageUrls: List[String])

val records = Q.query[String, (String,String)]("""
  SELECT
    users.name, images.url
  FROM
    users
    INNER JOIN images ON images.user_id = users.id
  WHERE
    users.name = ?
""").list(name)  

val users = records.groupBy(_._1).map(tup => User(tup._1, tup._2.map(_._2)))
```

When done, you will have an `Iterable[User]` as the `users` val.